# How can I send 2 parameters in data-ajax-success?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core

I write code that will be deleted from the product database. For this I need to perform in ajax that if the operation was performed then it will also delete the row in the table on the page.

the code behind -

```
public IActionResult OnPost (int id)
        {
            try
            {

                Order order = Order.Where (a => a.Id == id) .FirstOrDefault ();

                _context.Order.Remove (order);
                _context.SaveChanges ();

                JsonType returnJson = new JsonType {Status = 0, Massage = "success"};
                return new JsonResult (returnJson);
            }
            catch
            {

                JsonType returnJson = new JsonType {Status = 1, Massage = "canceled"};
                return new JsonResult (returnJson);
            }


        }
```

The code on the page-

```
   <form method = "post" asp-route-id = "@ item.Id" data-ajax = "true" data-ajax-confirm = "Are you sure?" data-ajax-success = "deleteItem (this)">
                           
                            <input type = "submit" value = "delete" asp-route-id = "@ item.Id" class = "dropdown-item" />
                        </form>
```

And the javascript code

```
  function deleteItem (form) {
                $ (form) .parent (). parent (). css ({
                    "display": "none"
                });
            }
```

The problem when the file fails, it also deletes the row in the table.
So I thought of getting the response.

```
    function deleteItem (response) {
              // if response ...
            }
```

But then I write the code on the page like this -

```
  <form .... data-ajax-success = "deleteItem">
....
                        </form>
```

And I can not get both data at the same time,

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<form method = "post" asp-route-id = "@ 
item.Id" data-ajax = "true" 
data-ajax-confirm = "Are you sure?" 
data-ajax-success = "deleteItem">
       <input type = "submit" value = "delete" asp-route-id = "@ item.Id" class = "dropdown-item" />
</form>
```

---

```
var deleteItem= function(context){
    console.log(context);
};
```

Comment: I wrote this with the question that this is how I get the response ... my question is how can I also get the "this" parameter so I can remove it in jquery

Comment: In response, you can return an Id or any unique name, and if the same unique id, name is available at the table row level, then you can delete that tr something like `$("uniqueid").remove()`